# How to ged rid of override all class when add new method in interface

Tags: java, methods, abstract, implements

I have interface, abstract method, and more classed and using these reference type as under.

```
   public interface InterfaceA {
    boolean mehod1();
    boolean method2();
    boolean newMethod(); //When added new method  
    }

public abstract class AbstractA implements InterfaceA{
// other common method

}


public Class C extend AbstractA //have to override three method
public Class D extend AbstractA //have to override three method
public Class E extend AbstractA //have to override three method but only should be override old method
public Class F extend AbstractA  //have to override three method  but only should be override old method
```

These classes derived AbstractA class I want to only new method in interface but only implement C and D class other should be use only old method.

How should design?

Comment: Use a default method?

Comment: either don't add it to the abstract class, or add an implemented version to the abstract class, or provide the implementations. a concrete class MUST provide an implementation for all the abstract methods of abstract classes it extends and all the interfaces implemented. that is the contract to respect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle it in two ways:

1. If you are using Java 7 or lower, extend the InterfaceA to create a new interface

```
    public InterfaceB extends InterfaceA{
    // Your new methods definitions here..
    }
```

Let Classes C and D implement InterfaceB.

2. If you are using Java 8 or higher, as @Slaw suggested, add default method to InterfaceA. Override the default implementation to give your custom implementation in Classes C and D

Answer (score 2):

You should think about one of SOLID rules - the `I` - "Interface segregation principle". You probably need to create a new interface, and your C and D classes can implement several interfaces. It is better design approach.

Comment: thanks, this is seeing important rule Interface segregation principle. I will define new interface

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you don't use inheritancy for what it is.
If C, D, E, F are A/AbstractA subclasses, any method defined in A should make sense for all these subclasses.
You cannot prevent the subclass inheritance for a method and allowed it for another.
If you need to introduce different concepts, use different hierarchies but don't try to design uniformaly things that are not.

About the best way to be DRY for common implementation in a hierarchy is moving the common implementation in abstract classes for methods that require instance fields and moving them in interface default methods for methods that don't require them.